# How to add material3 components to the XML design palette?

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, material-components-android

So I followed this guide [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md) on how to add material3 to the gradle and I was able to get the colors XML.However, when I go to the layout XML, the palette does not have any of material3's components (like their buttons, textviews...),
How do I add the components to the palette so that I can drag and drop them ?

Following the guide, I added dependency on the material3 in the settings.gradle.kts

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.name = "Proj1"
include(":app")
```

and I added the resources to the build.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.proj1"
    compileSdk = 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.proj1"
        minSdk = 27
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0-alpha03")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
}
```

but nothing changed

I tried replacing the 'button' component on XML with 'MaterialButton', but I got errors all over and nothing worked so I just went back to 'button'
I also tried adding a style attribute to the button component `style="@style/Widget.Material3.Button.ElevatedButton"`
but the button was not elevated, it just changed colors